# Does $R(X, Y)Y$ lie in the plane spanned by $X$ and $Y$?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curvature

Let $X$, $Y$ be tangent vectors to a point on a Riemannian manifold $(M, g)$. Clearly $R(X,Y)Y$ is orthogonal to $Y$. Is it nonetheless the case that $R(X,Y)Y$ lies in the span of $X$ and $Y$? If so, how is this proved? If not can you give a counterexample?

Answer (score 3):

If what you say is true for a manifold for any $X$ and $Y$ then, by taking $X$ orthogonal to $Y$, $R(X,Y)Y$, being orthogonal to $Y$, must be a multiple of $X$. Fixing a point and summing over a orthogonal basis of $\{X\}^{\perp}$, one gets that the Ricci operator of $X$ is a multiple of $X$. So $\operatorname{Ric}_p$ has every vector of $T_pM$ as eigenvectors. By linear algebra this implies that $\operatorname{Ric}_p=\lambda(p)g_p$, and since this is valid for every point, $g$ must be an Einstein metric. So any non Einstein metric is a counterexample.

Comment: When you say "a Ricci metric" you really mean "an Einstein metric."

Comment: Yes, thanks for the correction

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply and explanation, @Romulus. The issue comes up in a proof I'm reading in a published paper. Even with the typo there, it's hard to interpret one step in the proof except as asserting that R(X,Y)Y always lies in the span of X, Y. Perhaps as I keep reading the proof I'll see what the author must have meant -- or should have meant -- to get a valid proof.